# By clicking button on form1,it shouild display form2 with details of gridview

Tags: c#, winforms

When I open the form2 gridview, it displays blank as it contains already some details, it needs to click Add button on form2 to show the gridview details.what should I do for displaying the view immediately after clicking the Button on form1 instead of the button on form2.
I wrote the below code but I want to improve the code.please help
in form2 ADD button click i wrote this code:-

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\Invoice System.xlsx";
string con = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0;READONLY=FALSE'", filename);
using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(con))
{
    cn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Customers$] " + "([CustomerID],[Name],[Shortcode],[Address1],[Address2],[City],[PIN],[State],[GSTIN],[Category]) " + "VALUES(@value1,@value2,@value3,@value4,@value5,@value6,@value7,@value8,@value9,@value10)", cn);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", textBox1.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", textBox2.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", textBox3.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value4", textBox4.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value5", textBox5.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value6", textBox6.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value7", textBox7.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value8", textBox8.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value9", textBox9.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value10", textBox10.Text);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter cmd2;
    cmd2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Customers$]", con);
    DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
    cmd2.Fill(ds);
    MessageBox.Show("Record saved successfully");
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

in form1 button click i wrote below code:

```
var myForm = new Customers();
myForm.Show();
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: As a sidenote, you should be carefull with using `AddWithValue` [See this](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add a parameter to your Customers class.

initialize the dataset in your form1, pass it to the constructor of your customers class. and voila, you have the dataset available the second  you open your form